# oversize data with the same id value in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
$('.filter-name input').click(function() {
var array = [];
$('.filter-name input').each(function(i, v) {
    if ($(v).prop('checked')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).data("value");
        if (array.find(item => item.id === id)) {
            array.push({
                id: id,
                filter: name
            })
        } else {
            array.push({
                id: id,
                filter: name
            });
        }
    }
});
console.log(array); });
```

if the selected input id is the same, how to add the data as an array?

Example array :

```
$arr = array(
0 =>
array(
    'id' => '2',
    "filter" => array("Male", "Female")
),
1 =>
array(
    'id' => '1',
    "filter" => array("Pink","Blue")
),
2 =>
array(
    'id' => '3',
    "filter" => array("3+", "6+")
));
```

If the input id value is '2', I want to add the selected value value to the filter How can I add it as new if you don't have an ID value of '2'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the result of `array.find()` to a variable. Then you can push onto its `filter` array.

If nothing is found, create a new element, and make `filter` an array with the new name.

```js
$('.filter-name input').click(function() {
  var array = [];
  $('.filter-name input').each(function(i, v) {
    if ($(v).prop('checked')) {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      var name = $(this).data("value");
      var element = array.find(item => item.id === id);
      if (element) {
        element.filter.push(name);
      } else {
        array.push({
          id: id,
          filter: [name]
        });
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(array);
});
```